Spring Boot + ShedLock scheduler method starting but do nothing
I have a scheduler method, that works using Spring Boot 3 scheduling and the ShedLock library to handle distributed sheduling.
Shedlock uses a Postgres table for synchronization.
    @Scheduled(cron = "${integration.dictionary.scheduler.cron}")
    @SchedulerLock(name = "downloadProdCalendarScheduler",
            lockAtLeastFor = "${integration.dictionary.scheduler.lock.at-least-for}",
            lockAtMostFor = "${integration.dictionary.scheduler.lock.at-most-for}")
    public void downloadProdCalendar() {
        try {
            log.info("Try to update production calendar");
            LockAssert.assertLocked();
            prodCalendarService.downloadProdCalendar();
            log.info("Production calendar updated successfully");
        } finally {
            setMDCMessageType(MESSAGE);
        }
    }

Actuator metrics show that the method ran successfully. In the database table I see updated Shedlock records. But! The method doesn't do anything and I don't see any log messages. Even messages like "Try to update production calendar".
What could be the reason for this behaviour?
Different test environments have different behavior. In one environment everything is ok, but in another the behavior described above occurs. At a dead end, I can’t figure out where to move next.

What do you mean by "doesn't do anything"?
Can you share the code of the application?
If you see the updated record, that means to do something, maybe and run the scheduled method with some lock probably.
